# I Want To Save The Data In My Database Depending On The Catgory Of Data Chosen by User Like I Have 4 Lisiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, django-views

I Want To Save The Data In My Database Depending On The Catgory Of Data Chosen by User Like I Have 4 Lisitings Like APparetements, Food And Life, Car And Travelling  if User Selects Appartements Then Area, location Fields Are Showed An getiing Data And Saved Data Else Hidden and Disabled For Other Fields Like Food And Life, Car And Travellig.
MY COde Of MyListing.html

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="page-heading">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="top-text header-text">
            <h6>Add Plots In Your Listing</h6>
            <h2>If You Want To Buy The Plot Then Add It In Your Listing</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contact-page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="inner-content">
            <div class="row">
              
              <div class="col-lg-6 align-self-center">
                <form id="contact" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="row">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <label for="">Listing Type</label>
                        {{ form.listing_type }}
                            <label for="" >Area</label>
                            {{ form.area }}
                            <label for="">Location</label>
                            {{ form.location }}

                            <label for="">Price</label>
                            {{ form.price }}
                            <label for="">Title</label>
                            {{ form.title }}
                            <label for="">Upload An Image</label>
                            {{ form.image }}
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="main-button "><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Add Your Listing!</button>
                      </fieldset>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var categorySelect = $('#id_listing_type'); // Corrected selector
        var areaField = $('#id_area');
        var locationField = $('#id_location'); // Define locationField
    
        areaField.prop('disabled', true); // Disable the field initially
        locationField.prop('disabled', true);
    
        categorySelect.on('change', function() {
            var selectedCategory = $(this).val();
    
            if (selectedCategory === 'appartements') {
                areaField.prop('disabled', false); // Enable the field
                locationField.prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                areaField.prop('disabled', true); // Disable the field
                locationField.prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    
    

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, can't seem to understand what your issue exactly is, but seems like you want to save fields according to choices made in page,

well you can save all the fields including `selectedCategory` and display them accordingly, in that way it'll be easier for you to modify the frontend without worrying about backend and easily maintain it

and if you don't want to save all fields, then in backend get the `selectedCategory` value and depending upon it, set the value in django model object